# How to add multiple existing vmware tags using terraform

Tags: terraform, tags, vmware

This is how i am currently using them:

```
        # terraform.tfvars
        vsphere_tag_name ="Name"
        vsphere_tag_category ="Category"

        # var.tf
        variable "vsphere_tag_name" {
        type        = string
        description = "Tag name for the vSphere virtual machines"
        }
        variable "vsphere_tag_category" {
        type        = string
        description = "Tag category for the vSphere virtual machines"
        }

        # main.tf data
        data "vsphere_tag_category" "category" {
        name = "${var.vsphere_tag_category}"
        }

        data "vsphere_tag" "tag" {
        name        = "${var.vsphere_tag_name}"
        category_id = "${data.vsphere_tag_category.category.id}"
        }
        # main.tf resource 
        tags        = ["${data.vsphere_tag.tag.id}"]
```

Works perfectly fine for one tag but how to give multiple existing tags?

Comment: You loop over them and create multiple tags.

Comment: any example would be awesome

Comment: You can't add tags with `data` providers. You would need `resource` for this. Can you format your code & add the resource block adding tags?

Comment: harshavmb i can change the code if i have to. just have to use the existing tags with their respective category. very new to terraform too, so just trying to get my head around :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the exact use case would be, especially as the required arguments for the tagging data sources are fairly strict, but it can be done.

Example:

```
    # terraform.tfvars
    vsphere_tag_name = ["Name1", "Name2", "Name3"]
    vsphere_tag_category = "Category"

    # var.tf
    variable "vsphere_tag_name" {
      type        = list
      description = "List of tag names for the vSphere virtual machines"
    }

    variable "vsphere_tag_category" {
      type        = string
      description = "Tag category for the vSphere virtual machines"
    }

    # main.tf data
    data "vsphere_tag_category" "category" {
      name = "${var.vsphere_tag_category}"
    }

    data "vsphere_tag" "tag" {
      for_each = var.vsphere_tag_name

      name        = "${each.value}"
      category_id = "${data.vsphere_tag_category.category.id}"
    }

    # main.tf resource 
    tags        = ["${data.vsphere_tag.tag[0].id}", "${data.vsphere_tag.tag[1].id}", "${data.vsphere_tag.tag[2].id}"]
```

Then, there's a whole other level of complexity if you have to switch vSphere Tag Category.

Comment: Appreciate it Kyle, unfortunately every existing tag have their own category too.

Comment: You could probably get real crazy by establishing the tag category name and tag name as a map typed variable, turn the two tag-related data sources into a module, then use a `for_each` with the module which iterates through each variable input and outputs the tag ID. Possible, but ... complex.

Answer (score 0):

Appreciate the help everyone involved, here is the answer

```
 # terraform.tfvars
    tags = {  
    TagCategory1             = "TagName1"
    TagCategory2             = "TagName2"
    }
    # var.tf
    variable "tags" {
    type        = map(any)
    }
    variable "tag_ids" {
    type        = list(any)
    }

    # main.tf data
    data "vsphere_tag_category" "category" {
    count      = length(var.tags)     
    name       = keys(var.tags)[count.index]
    }
    data "vsphere_tag" "tag" {
    count       = length(var.tags)
    name        = var.tags[keys(var.tags)[count.index]]
    category_id = data.vsphere_tag_category.category[count.index].id
    }
    # main.tf resource 
    tags          = var.tag_ids:data.vsphere_tag.tag[*].id
```

Answer (score 0):

Found this thread and it helped, thanks. Here is the working solution we came up with.

```
#terraform.auto.tfvars   
tag_categories = {
  "Environment" = {
    name = "Environment"
    tags = ["dev", "test", "prod"]
  }
  "OS" = {
    name = "OS"
    tags = ["linux", "windows"]
  }
}

#variables.tf    
variable "tag_categories" {
  description = "Multiple tags / categories"
  type = map(object({
    name = string
    tags = list(string)
  }))
}

#main.tf
locals {
  categories = merge([for c in var.tag_categories : {
    for t in c.tags : "${c.name}-${t}" => {
      tag      = t
      category = c.name
    }
  }]...)
}

resource "vsphere_tag_category" "category" {
  for_each    = { for k, v in var.tag_categories : k => k }
  name        = each.key
  cardinality = "SINGLE"
  description = "Managed by Terraform"

  associable_types = [
    "VirtualMachine",
    "Datastore",
  ]
}

resource "vsphere_tag" "tag" {
  for_each    = local.categories
  category_id = vsphere_tag_category.category[each.value.category].id
  name        = each.value.tag
  description = "Managed by Terraform"
}

resource "vsphere_virtual_machine" "tag_test" {
  # ... other configuration ...

  tags = ${for t in vsphere_tag.tag : t.id}
}
```